# Maya Python: Making clusters on curve CVs

Tags: python, maya, curves

I've found all the CV's on a curve, and I'd like to make a cluster on each one. But I'm getting an error that isn't super helpful. Here's the code:

```
# Find all the CVs on the curve, loop through and create a cluster on each
curveCVs = cmds.ls(targetCurve + ".cv[0:]",fl=True)
for i, cv in enumerate(curveCVs):
print i, cv

cmds.cluster(wn=(cv, cv))
```

The error is on the arguments for the wn flag in cmds.cluster.

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 211: Invalid transforms specified.
```

The docs say the arguments should be a strings. E.g. wn=("thing1", "thing2")

But even if I try manually entering the CV strings, it doesn't work.

```
cmds.cluster(wn=("targetPath.cv[14]", "targetPath.cv[14]"))
```

Is there another approach to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Here's how you use `cmds.cluster`:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

targetCurve = 'curve1' # Curve to put clusters on
curveCVs = cmds.ls('{0}.cv[:]'.format(targetCurve), fl = True) # Get all cvs from curve
if curveCVs: # Check if we found any cvs
    for cv in curveCVs:
        print 'Creating {0}'.format(cv)
        cmds.cluster(cv) # Create cluster on a cv
else:
    cmds.warning('Found no cvs!')
```

Comment: Ah, the simplest solution is the answer -- thank you!